# How to access a object from a different file

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python I have been using classes alot for a project I am working on. I know that you have to use an object to access a class in python however I am wondering how to access an object from a different file. SO:

file1.py

```
class Class1:
    vara = 0
    varb = 10
```

file2.py

```
import file1
object1 = file1.Class1()
```

file3.py

```
#This is where I want to access object1
```

Comment: Since you already know how to import, why can't you do that in file3?

Comment: woops, just a mistype. I fixed it

Comment: No, my point is that you already used `import` to bring names from file1 into file2. So why can't you use it again to bring names from file2 into file3?

Comment: @Daniel I was replying to someone else, as I accidently imported file1.py instead of file1

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Also I don't think that works for objects

Comment: Sure it does. Python doesn't make any distinction between classes and objects, or anything else; it's all just names.

Comment: @Daniel Nope I just tested it. It didn't work, however the answer by Write did seem to work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Well I tested it and it worked. I do apologise, I tried that before and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import it as you did `Class1`, like `Class1` in `file1.py`, `object1` is just another name in the namespace for `file2.py`:

```
from file2 import object1
```

or, if you don't want to bring `object1` in the new modules' namespace, just import `file2` and access `object1`:

```
import file2

print(file2.object1)
```

Comment: Hu, this is kind of odd, I tried this earlier but it didn't work, but now it does. Thank you very much!